# WPF TreeView ItemTemplate not applied to TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, itemtemplate

I have a `TreeView` and manually add two items (`TreeViewItem`) to it.
And I want to apply `ItemTemplate` to those two items but it seems like the `ItemTemplate` is not applied to them. Actually I have deeper levels in the tree (so item1 and item2 each has a collection as `ItemsSource`, and there are more `HierarchicalDataTemplates` for them). But to demonstrate the first Template NOT being applied to the first-level items, I simplified the example.  Below are the behind codes.

```
        TreeViewItem item1 = new TreeViewItem();
        TreeViewItem item2 = new TreeViewItem();
        trvRecordList.Items.Add(item1);
        trvRecordList.Items.Add(item2);
```

And here are my xaml codes. The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is written in a correct place.

```
                      <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="My_Template">                                                      
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="Images/Star_Blue.png"
                                       Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                <TextBox Text="abcd"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


                      <TreeView Name="trvRecordList" Margin="2"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource My_Template}">                           
                     </TreeView>
```

Comment: HierarchicalDataTemplate needs Treeview's ItemsSource property filled.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding a list of `TreeViewItem` objects to your `TreeView`, My_Template will not be applied to it. If you check your output window, you would be getting an error as shown below

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TreeViewItem'
```

The solution is to apply My_Template to the `ItemTemplate` property of the `TreeViewItem` itself. 
Below are the modifications I've done to your code

```
        TreeViewItem item1 = new TreeViewItem();
        TreeViewItem item2 = new TreeViewItem();
        item1.Items.Add("");
        item1.Items.Add("");
        item1.ItemTemplate = FindResource("My_Template") as HierarchicalDataTemplate;

        item2.Items.Add("");
        item2.Items.Add("");
        item2.ItemTemplate = FindResource("My_Template") as HierarchicalDataTemplate;

        trvRecordList.Items.Add(item1);
        trvRecordList.Items.Add(item2);
```

Go through the below link to learn more about HierarchicalDataTemplate

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx

Edit:

If you want to apply My_Template to the `TreeView` then try this code.

```
        trvRecordList.Items.Add("");
        trvRecordList.Items.Add("");
```

Comment: But, I want to apply My_Template to item1 itself! not to the children of item1.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't use TreeViewItem, I have edited by answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemTemplate` is for data objects. Check the remarks for [ItemTemplate on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx).

`TreeViewItem` is container generated for each data item and is styled thru `ItemContainerTemplate`. [ItemContainerTemplate on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx)